# Storing computations in arrays - second try

Tags: java

im new to Java and currently trying to learn how to best store numbers in arrays.

the specific problem im working on is trying to find a way to better implement the below methods by storing the computations in an array.

the code looks like this:

```
public static long myF(int N) {
  long[] computedValues;
  computedValues = new long[N+1];
  computedValues[0] = 0;
  computedValues[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < computedValues.length ;i++){
        computedValues[i] = computedValues[(i-1)]+computedValues[(i-2)];
        System.out.println("array["+(i)+"] = "+computedValues[i]);  
    }
        return computedValues[N-1];
    }   
    public static void runMyF() {
       for (int N = 0; N < 100; N++)
          StdOut.println(N + " " + myF(N));
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runMyF ();
    }
```

Main in this code is supposed to call runMyF(), and then runMyF() is supposed to call myF().
My problem is that I cant get computedValues[0] = 0; computedValues[1] = 1; included in the output and the second problem is that ie get this error message when runMyF() calls myF():

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at algs11.MyFib.myF(MyFib.java:21)
at algs11.MyFib.runMyF(MyFib.java:30)
at algs11.MyFib.main(MyFib.java:37)
```

Any help please?
@Dukeling, your solution was a bit over my pay grade (sorry) - I think there are some bugs in my code and I need help to find them. Thank you.

Comment: What you are trying to do is something called memoization. Usually it's done with a dictionary, or a HashMap in Java. It's possible to do it with an array, but probably a little clunky. I'd read up on dynamic programming to get a feel for how to do it.

Comment: F(N-2) is meant to be the element 2-before. Not a N-2 value. F(N-1) means the last element, not N-1 value.

Comment: is this homework related to recursion? Otherwise, recursion is really not the best way to generate Fibonacci numbers. Use Binet's approximation, which states that F_n is the nearest integer to (0.5(1+SQRT(5)))^n

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question instead of modifying a question that had already been answered (that makes the answers obsolete which is not nice for those who spent some time on your problem).

Comment: Well it didn't really changes the question and I was still working with one of the guys who answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're incrementing the wrong variable.

  ```
  for (int i = 2; i < computedValues.length; N++){
  ```

  should be

  ```
  for (int i = 2; i < computedValues.length; i++){
  ```

  Note the `N++` changed to `i++`.
- Remember to initialize `computedValues[0]` and `computedValues[1]`. This should appear before the loop:

  ```
  computedValues[0] = 0;
  if (N > 0) // needed because when N = 0, the below will be out of bounds
    computedValues[1] = 1;
  ```
- It should probably be `computedValues = new long[N+1];`, otherwise the array is too small.
- You need to return the correct value - change `return computedValues[N];` to `return 0;`.

**Additional efficiency:**

I guess the point is to compare the efficiency of the two method. If not, you should declare `computedValues` outside of the function as an `ArrayList` and, in the function, add to it as required. This will cause you to only compute each value once for the entire run of the program.

```
static ArrayList<Long> computedValues = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(0l,1l));

public static long myF(int N) {
    for (int i = computedValues.size(); i <= N; i++){
         computedValues.add(computedValues.get(i-1) + computedValues.get(i-2));
         System.out.println("array[" + i + "] = " + computedValues.get(i));
    }
    return computedValues.get(N);
}
```

Comment: thanks .... but there is still a problem when the method runMyF() is being called, don't see why though?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: @Snarre As per your suggested edit (which should've been a comment), you should include that before the loop.

Comment: sorry about that - I just though it would have been easier for you to read it. Im a bit confused here. looking at the initial code, the actual computation is done in the method called runF(), I need to get the result this method produce into myF() which will store each computation into an array.

Comment: @Snarre With my proposed changes, it's not necessary to call `F` at all. Index `i` in the array corresponds to the value `F(i)` will return.

Comment: your solution was a bit over my pay grade (sorry) - I think there are some bugs in my code and I need help to find them. Thank you. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @Snarre You need to include `if (N > 0)` as I did, otherwise when `N = 0`, you'll make `computedValues` with size 1, thus `computedValues[1]` will be out of bounds.

Comment: I still get the following error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at algs11.MyFib.myF(MyFib.java:23)
 at algs11.MyFib.runMyF(MyFib.java:32)
 at algs11.MyFib.main(MyFib.java:39)

Comment: You need to also return `computerValues[N]` (not `N-1`). See [this](http://ideone.com/tolbdq) for a working version.

Comment: Thanks! on thing I wonder about though, why does the computation start with 9 and not 1 or 0?

Comment: What do you mean the computation stats at 9?

Comment: well in the console I get th following: 
array[9] = 34
array[10] = 55
array[11] = 89
array[12] = 144 ETC..... So it starts with array[9]....why not array[0]?

Comment: The example [here](http://ideone.com/tolbdq) doesn't. If you're code's the same, the first few lines has likely just been truncated from the output.

Comment: hmm ok.. thank you so much for your help - you've been great!

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing computedValues to a new long

```
computedValues = new long[N];
```

I think you wanted to do this :

```
computedValues[i] = F(N);
```

Also, in your loop you are not incementing i which makes it as infinite loop. Change it to

```
for (int i = 2; i < computedValues.length ;i++)
```

Comment: The whole point is efficiency. Basing the values in the array off of the inefficient version is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the initial numbers in the array:

```
long[] computedValues;
computedValues = new long[N];
computedValues[0] = 0;
computedValues[1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method that returns an arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Long>series=new ArrayList<Long>();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  if(i==0)series.add(new Long(0));
  if(i==1)series.add(new Long(1));
  if(i>1)series.add(new Long(series.get(i-1).longValue()+series.get(i-2).longValue()));
}
```

the list will have 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,....